# Solr : How to implement this logic?

Tags: solr

I have the following scenario. Suppose I have table a big table like this.

```
Id(unique)     returnMe             desc                       name         value
1              user1            all those living in usa        country           USA
2.             user2            all those like game            game              football
3.             user1            my hobbies are                 hobby             guitar
```

Now, how can I get results (returnMe) for following queries.

```
1. For all those users who live in usa AND like guitar
2. For all those users who live in usa OR like guitar.
```

Please donot modify query in anyway.

For my solConfig.xml 'desc' , 'name' , 'value' are searchable , indexable fields.

Thanks for any help.

Well I am editing this to explain my logic ..

```
Step 1: Break query on AND like (live in USA) AND (like guitar)
Step 2: Then select returnMes from first query and returnMes from second query.
Step 3: Take common returnMes, returned from first query and second query.
```

Is there any way Solr can do that. Can we do it through Solr "join" or not or some otherway ??
I do want to do that in my PHP , it would be massive overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to modify the query in some way.  A simple step to parse the query and add parentheses to it, and possibly field names to search.  You could reasonably easily transform those queries into something like:

```
(For all those users who live in usa) AND (like guitar)
(For all those users who live in usa) OR (like guitar)
```

or perhaps you can cut out "for all those users who" and have simply:

```
(live in usa) AND (like guitar)
(live in usa) OR (like guitar)
```

And set the query field to `value`.  Of course, you could run into issues, if you had a document with `value=users`, or something of that nature, since it will search for each term present in the `value` field.

If you really want to be able to work with natural language, than you can take look at the [OpenNLP](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP) project.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your suggestions. I have edited my question a bit to explain my logic. Can you please look into this to help me out.

Comment: Why would you manually merge results?  The Solr query parser supports boolean logic.  Why not just pass the query `(live in usa) AND (like guitar)`

Comment: Because 'AND' try to find (live in usa) and (like guitar) document wise( both queries should be present in document ) . For example - If I simply do AND on above table then I will not get any result becuase none of the document satisfy both query.  But my requirement is to get "user1" for query "living in usa and hobby is guitar" .. Any solution . I stuck in this :(

Comment: Ah, I see.  Maybe.  Not sure if Solr supports things like: `q={!join from=returnMe to=returnMe}value:(this AND that)`, give it a shot I suppose.  Better solution would be to denormalize your data into multivalued fields, which would be better equipped to perform your search.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will dig into join and try to find out :) .. thanks for your suggestions and help :)